# Parse.com login brute force protection

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

As I know, Parse.com's Parse.logIn method is not protected from brute forcing.

I can implement my own login method with all the features I need, but Parse.logIn method still will be available on client side, allowing users which are familiar with Parse API to make brute-force attack directly from browsers.

So the question is: how can one change or disable Parse.logIn method?

Comment: Does brute forcing means that we can try the username/password very frequently?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can launch a loop in browser which will guess the password.

Comment: What about if you created cloud code method for logging in users and put some checks in there for number of times trying to enter in password?